# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Tags: pear

i am having issues with installing PEAR in my wamp server 2.5 . Here my steps :

1) Create a new folder c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\PEAR 
2) Get go-pear.phar from [pear.php.net] and save it into the php5.5.12 folder
3) open command prompt and go to "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\PEAR> 
then type "php go-pear.phar" . It successfully installed on my wamp server but i execute below code :

"require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));"

showing error :

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') .

I type "pear" in command line in my installed wamp server direcory and it's working. Can anyone know the reason ??

Thanks.